# COPY to STDOUT Postgres - header cells not quoted

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am running this from Python to a PostgreSQL DB.

`COPY (<select query here>) TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, QUOTE '\"', FORCE_QUOTE *, ENCODING 'UTF8' )`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

All cells returned in the CSV are quoted except for the header ones?!

How do I make them quoted too?
Is that a Postgres issue or a psycopg2 issue?

Comment: `QUOTE` only refers to the data values. The `HEADER`/column names are not quoted and AFAIK cannot be. This is on `COPY`/Postgres end.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Hm... But what if the column/header names come e.g. from a SELECT statement, and they contain some unpleasant characters? We need to quote them, no? So what is the solution or the workaround in this case?

Comment: You can quote them in the `SELECT` e.g. `SELECT "some fld" ...`. They will show up in the `CSV` unquoted though. Not sure what the issue is though, headers are not data.